# Percentage comparison to/by/of/in

Tags: american-english, comparisons, percentages

I am trying to see if there is a general rule for for percentage comparisons when it comes to additive or multiplicative results. For example, lets say I have 100 apples. I could say:

- My apples have **increased by 200%** to 300 apples.
- I have had a **200% increase in** apples. I now have 300 apples.
- If I have an **increase of 200%**, I would have 300 apples.
- 150 apples is **50% more** than my original 100 apples.

however I could also say this:

- If I have **150% of** my original 100 apples, then I have 150 apples.
- My apples have increased **to 200% of** my original apples. I have 200 apples.

[From what I can find, this appears to be the difference between an absolute change and relative change in percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage#Percentage_increase_and_decrease). Is the inclusion of a comparison word like `increase` or `more` the determining factor when deciding whether the original 100% is included or excluded from the comparison? Does the inclusion of `to` negate the comparison words effects, making it an absolute and not relative comparison?

Comment: This is an ELL question. Have you tried asking your question over there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own examples show that the 'comparison word', as you call it, cannot be the determining factor. Consider the following two examples you provided:

*My supply of apples has **increased by** 200%, to 300 apples.*
(the original quantity **excluded**)

*My supply of apples has **increased to** 200% of my original supply, so now I have 200 apples.*
(the original quantity **included**)

Same 'comparison word' (the verb *increase*), different 'inclusion' properties. So, no, the 'comparison word' is not decisive. Note that in the case of the verb *increase,* in order to say anything quantitative about the amount of increase, we must use a preposition phrase (PP) complement.

Note that this has nothing especially to do with percentages. If I had 60 kg and gained 10 kg so that now I have 70 kg, I can describe that using either of the following:

*My weight has **increased by** 10 kg.* 
*My weight has **increased to** 70 kg.*

All I can say is that the prepositions *by* and *to* work in this way (*by* having the 'exclusive' meaning, *to* having the inclusive one) with many other verbs besides *increase*. Some examples include *swell, boost, expand, surge, rise* and many others (and their antonyms like *decrease, contract, decline, shrink,* etc.).

With the noun *increase*, we have something similar. Say that initially there were 40,000 units, which the Ministry projects to increase by 10,000 units to 50,000 units total. We can say

*The Ministry projects a 10,000-unit increase.*
*The Ministry projects an increase of 10,000 units.*
*The Ministry projects an increase to 50,000 units.*

In the case of *more*, when it follows a quantity, it **is** determinative, in the sense that it is always interpreted as 'additional':

*All I need is **$5 more.***

Your next-to-last example is indeed specific to percentages and fractions. Here the presence or absence of other words matters. For example,

*If I **have** 150% of my original 100 apples, then I have 150 apples.*
*If I **have an additional** 150% of my original 100 apples, then I have 250 apples.*

Similarly,

*If I **have** a double of my original 100 apples, then I have 200 apples.*
*If I **have an additional** double of my original 100 apples, then I have 300 apples.*